# Issues running junit5 beforeall method before app startup along with spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-cloud-contract

I am running an Integration test using SpringBootTest annotation where AutoConfigureStubRunner annotation is used to startup a stub runner. I am using a method annotated with BeforeAll to run certain operations before the SpringBootApplication is started up which is the expected behaviour with BeforeAll.
However, my application is starting up first and only after this the BeforeAll block is executed.

However when I remove the spring-cloud-stub-runner this is working as expected(BeforeAll gets executed first and then the application is started up)

Spring boot version: 2.5.3

Spring cloud version: 2020.0.3

Java version: 16(also tried with 11)

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = MainApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH,
        ids = "${..}"
)
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("local")
class SampleIT {
  @BeforeAll
    static void setupTestClass() {
       //do stuff
    }
}
```

```
               <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
```

Once I deleted the above dependency it starts working, this is weird as I have used the same dependency following the same pattern before

Comment: I am able to fix it if I either use spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner instead of the corresponding starter. This remove the spring-cloud-contract-wiremock dependency which was causing this issue. I am still not sure about the reason for this behaviour